# watermark image in CListCtrl

Tags: image, mfc, clistctrl

I want to draw an transparent watermak image in the bottom right corner of my CListCtrl.

How can you do that with MFC? (I need that without flickers).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [my blog post here](http://tortoisesvn.net/listcontrolbackground.html) where I describe in detail how this can be done.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, now the image looks fine, but now the text flickers.

Answer (score 0):

m_List1.SetExtendedStyle( m_List1.GetExtendedStyle() | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT | **LVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER**  )
solved the flickering problem.

But how u controled the icon transparency like in your image (ownerdrawn.png)?